# How to get a blank value in lookup?

Tags: excel

I have a lookup formula that I currently use to gather information from a different page in my spreadsheet:

```
=(VLOOKUP($A$3,Lookup!$A$3:$AG$472,2,FALSE)*0.01)
```

But if there is no data in the cell of the lookup page, it returns a value of `0`. I would like the cell to remain blank, the same as the original cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A$3,Lookup!$A$3:$AG$472,2,FALSE)="","",VLOOKUP($A$3,Lookup!$A$3:$AG$472,2,FALSE)*0.01)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you do not have a Circular Reference.  If the value is missing in the other sheet, it should return `#N/A`, not `0`.  The circular reference would occur if the cell containing your formula is `A3`.
2. To get around the problem, use:

   ```
   =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$3,Lookup!$A$3:$AG$472,2,FALSE)*0.01, "")
   ```

Again, the missing value should return `#N/A` in the `VLOOKUP`.  The `IFERROR` should catch that and let you return the value you want to.  It appears you have a circular reference which would return `0`.

Comment: This is not about missing data, but about the lookup value being found, but the respective cell to be returned is empty. Any formula that refers to an empty cell will return a zero.